# I have run into an error with my basic calculator

Tags: vb.net

I need help with storing a variable as either a +, -, /, *,. I cannot figure it out and im fairly a noob. I made it through a console application on Vb.net

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Do
        Dim UserInput As Object = Nothing
        Dim UserInputNum1 As Object = Nothing
        Dim UserInputNum2 As Object = Nothing
        Dim UserAnswer As Object = Nothing

        Console.WriteLine("Slect Your First Number")
        UserInputNum1 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("You Slected: " & UserInputNum1)
        Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("Slect Your Second Number")
        UserInputNum2 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("You Slected: " & UserInputNum2)
        Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("Would You Like To + - * /")
        UserInput = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("You Slected: " & UserInput)
        Console.ReadLine()

        If UserInput = + Then
            UserAnser = UserInputNum1 + UserInputNum2
        End If

        If UserInput = - Then
            UserAnser = UserInputNum1 - UserInputNum2
        End If

        If UserInput = * Then
            UserAnser = UserInputNum1 * UserInputNum2
        End If

        If UserInput = / Then
            UserAnser = UserInputNum1 / UserInputNum2
        End If

        Console.WriteLine(UserInputNum1 & " " & UserInput & " " & UserInputNum2 & " = " & UserAnswer)
        Console.ReadLine()
    Loop
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Your title says there is an error.  What is the error?

Comment: Is there an actual question?

Comment: Try putting quotes around the operators in your If statements: `If UserInput = "+" Then`, etc.  Also get in the habit of converting data types properly - VB.NET can be sloppy and may let you do things like `UserAnswer = UserInputNum1 + UserInputNum2`, but take advantage of the strongly-typed nature of .NET and rather than objects use proper data types - like `Dim UserAnswer As Double` and `UserAnswer = CType(UserInputNum1, Double) + CType(UserInput2, Double)`

Comment: Although `Double.TryParse` would be safer in the above example.

Comment: @Tim: `Option Strict On` should help achieve that. :)

Comment: @Neolisk - Yep, that it will.  I couldn't remember off the top of my head which of the settings in VB.NET would do that.  It should be the default, IMO - to prevent bad programming practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use Console.ReadKey() to get the input and then use a mSelect Case block to process it.  See if this helps:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Do
        Dim UserInput As Char = Nothing
        Dim UserInputNum1 As Object = Nothing
        Dim UserInputNum2 As Object = Nothing
        Dim UserAnswer As Object = Nothing

        Console.WriteLine("Slect Your First Number")
        UserInputNum1 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("You Slected: " & UserInputNum1)
        Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("Slect Your Second Number")
        UserInputNum2 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("You Slected: " & UserInputNum2)
        Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("Would You Like To + - * /")
        UserInput = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar
        Console.WriteLine(UserInput)
        Console.ReadLine()
        Select Case UserInput
            Case "+"c
                UserAnser = UserInputNum1 + UserInputNum2

            Case "-"c
                UserAnser = UserInputNum1 - UserInputNum2

            Case "*"c
                UserAnser = UserInputNum1 * UserInputNum2

            Case "/"
                UserAnser = UserInputNum1 / UserInputNum2

        Console.WriteLine(UserInputNum1 & " " & UserInput & " " & UserInputNum2 & " = " & UserAnswer)
        Console.ReadLine()
    Loop
End Sub

End Module
```

The `c` at the end of a string literal is VB's way of denoting a 1 character string as a Char